# Aggregate each row and create new monthly column for the weeks to a month

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2017, transaction

I appreciate all your help. Below is my query and request.

Here is my staging table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  [WC] nvarchar(255),
  [Requestor] nvarchar(255),
  [MTR#] nvarchar (255),
  [Date Added] nvarchar(255),
  [Use Case] nvarchar(255),
  [Prog Account] nvarchar(255),
  [SB#] nvarchar(255),
  [CO#] nvarchar(255),
  [Job #] nvarchar(255),
  [Need Date] nvarchar(255),
  [Totals] nvarchar,
  [221] nvarchar(255),
  [7-Oct-22] nvarchar(255),
  [14-Oct-22] nvarchar(255),
  [21-Oct-22] nvarchar(255),
  [28-Oct-22] nvarchar(255),
  [4-Nov-22] nvarchar(255),
  [11-Nov-22] nvarchar(255),
  [18-Nov-22] nvarchar(255),
  [25-Nov-22] nvarchar(255),
  [2-Dec-22] nvarchar(255),
  [9-Dec-22] nvarchar(255),
  [16-Dec-22] nvarchar(255),
  [23-Dec-22] nvarchar(255),
  [30-DEC-22] nvarchar(255),
  [6-Jan-23] nvarchar(255),
  [13-Jan-23] nvarchar(255),
  [20-Jan-23] nvarchar(255),
  [27-Jan-23] nvarchar(255),
  [3-Feb-23] nvarchar(255),
  [10-Feb-23] nvarchar(255),
  [17-Feb-23] nvarchar(255),
  [24-Feb-23] nvarchar(255),
  [3-Mar-23] nvarchar(255),
  [10-Mar-23] nvarchar(255),
  [17-Mar-23] nvarchar(255),
  [24-Mar-23] nvarchar(255),
  [31-Mar-23] nvarchar(255),
  [7-Apr-23] nvarchar(255),
  [14-Apr-23] nvarchar(255),
  [21-Apr-23] nvarchar(255),
  [28-Apr-23] nvarchar(255),
  [5-May-23] nvarchar(255),
  [12-May-23] nvarchar(255),
  [19-May-23] nvarchar(255),
  [26-May-23] nvarchar(255))
```

This is the insert:

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].MyTable
         ([WC]
         ,[Requestor]
         ,[MTR#]
         ,[Date Added]
         ,[Use Case]
         ,[Prog Account]
         ,[SB#]
         ,[CO#]
         ,[Job #]
         ,[Need Date]
         ,[Totals]
         ,[221]
         ,[7-Oct-22]
         ,[14-Oct-22]
         ,[21-Oct-22]
         ,[28-Oct-22]
         ,[4-Nov-22]
         ,[11-Nov-22]
         ,[18-Nov-22]
         ,[25-Nov-22]
         ,[2-Dec-22]
         ,[9-Dec-22]
         ,[16-Dec-22]
         ,[23-Dec-22]
         ,[30-Dec-22]
         ,[6-Jan-23]
         ,[13-Jan-23]
         ,[20-Jan-23]
         ,[27-Jan-23]
         ,[3-Feb-23]
         ,[10-Feb-23]
         ,[17-Feb-23]
         ,[24-Feb-23]
         ,[3-Mar-23]
         ,[10-Mar-23]
         ,[17-Mar-23]
         ,[24-Mar-23]
         ,[31-Mar-23]
         ,[7-Apr-23]
         ,[14-Apr-23]
         ,[21-Apr-23]
         ,[28-Apr-23]
  ,[5-May-23]
         ,[12-May-23]
         ,[19-May-23]
         ,[26-May-23]
         )
   VALUES
('TL','XUpgrade','4523XXXX','4/1/2022', 'Road Kit', 'KKK, 1.1, BA.111','','','','', 0,'123456',1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,1,7,8,8,1,9,4,9,2,0,9,9,0,8,8,8,7,6,6,6),
  ('TA','XUpgrade-1','14523XXXX','4/11/2022', 'Tool Kit', 'AAA, 1.10, BA.222','90909','SQAre12','meta0909','4/19/2023', 0,'123456',1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,4,3,8,9,2,1,9,9,9,9,0,8,8,8,7,6,6,6),
  ('TK','XUpgrade-22','24523XXXX','4/12/2022', 'Safe Kit', 'QQQ, 1.11, BA.989','909079','Spare12','metaop0909','9/19/2023', 0,'123456',1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,8,8,8,7,6,6,6),
  ('TG','XUpgrade-22','34523XXXX','4/13/2022', 'No Kit', 'ASD, 1.19, BA.909','909079','parkre12','metaIns0909','8/19/2023', 0,'123456',1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,1,2,3,4,9,9,9,0,8,8,8,7,6,6,6),
  ('AP','XUpgrade-33','44523XXXX','4/4/2022', 'Yes Kit', 'DFG, 1.881, BA.987','909079','kkkre12','metaFB0909','7/19/2023', 0,'123456',1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,0,7,7,8,2,8,1,9,2,1,9,1,9,0,8,8,8,7,6,6,6),
  ('RL','XUpgrade-00','94523XXXX','4/15/2022', 'Car Kit', 'MNB, 1.991, BA.0909','909079','zzAre12','FB0909','4/19/2023', 0,'123456',1,1,1,2,2,0,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,1,8,8,1,1,1,3,0,1,9,0,8,8,8,7,6,6,6)
        
     GO
```

In the staging table, the first 12 columns are constant every time I load the file into the staging table. The other columns are every Friday of each month from the current month. For example, this month is October 2022, so it will be columns of four Fridays.

I want to sum the data of each row for each month and should populate the data into the destination table.

Below is the expected output in the Destination table.

```
 [WC]|[Requestor]|[MTR#]|[Date Added]|[Use Case]|[Prog Account]|[SB#]|[CO#]|[Job #]|[Need Date]|[Totals]|[221]|Month1|Month2|Month3|Month4|Month5|Month6|Month7|Month8
 TL|XUpgrade|4523XXXX|4/1/2022| Road Kit| KKK| 1.1| BA.111||||| 0|123456|5|12|26|22|22|29|24|25
 TA|XUpgrade-1|14523XXXX|4/11/2022| Tool Kit| AAA| 1.10| BA.222|90909|SQAre12|meta0909|4/19/2023|0|123456|5|12|26|24|22|37|24|25
 TK|XUpgrade-22|24523XXXX|4/12/2022| Safe Kit| QQQ| 1.11| BA.989|909079|Spare12|metaop0909|9/19/2023|0|123456|5|12|26|28|20|10|24|25
 TG|XUpgrade-22|34523XXXX|4/13/2022| No Kit| ASD| 1.19| BA.909|909079|parkre12|metaIns0909|8/19/2023|0|123456|5|12|26|28|19|34|24|25
 AP|XUpgrade-33|44523XXXX|4/4/2022| Yes Kit| DFG| 1.881| BA.987|909079|kkkre12|metaFB0909|7/19/2023|0|123456|5|12|26|22|20|22|24|25
 RL|XUpgrade-00|94523XXXX|4/15/2022| Car Kit| MNB| 1.991| BA.0909|909079|zzAre12|FB0909|4/19/2023|0|123456|5|9|26|21|18|14|24|25
```

For example if you see the first 4 columns of week for first row: [7-Oct-22], [14-Oct-22], [21-Oct-22], [28-Oct-22] the values are 1,1,1,2 so in the output it should be 5 and the column should be Month0.

In the above example, I have just shared only 7 months, but the actual data I have is rolling 25 months up to Dec 2024. My staging table in November will start from November 2022 columns.

SQL Version : Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0

Could you please help me and assist on how to build the query for this?

Comment: I agree, this is a really bad design. Ideally this table would contain just the first few columns plus a date column. It's going to be really difficult and tedious to build a query to get that data into shape.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker  : This is actually a file that i loaded into a Staging table.

Comment: Unpivot is your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My SQL-centric approach is to loop through the columns that look like dates in the staging table and group them together into the target month numbers. From that, you can build up some dynamic SQL that will dump the output in a single set-based operation.  With some tweaking and error handling, something like the following code should get you there. Depending on what you’re doing with the destination data, you might be better off at this point going for a row per month rather than maintaining the pivoting across the columns. It shouldn’t be too hard to change the code to dump out a SQL statement per month.

```
drop table if exists dbo.Destination
create table dbo.Destination
(
  [WC] nvarchar(255),
  [Requestor] nvarchar(255),
  [MTR#] nvarchar (255),
  [Date Added] nvarchar(255),
  [Use Case] nvarchar(255),
  [Prog Account] nvarchar(255),
  [SB#] nvarchar(255),
  [CO#] nvarchar(255),
  [Job #] nvarchar(255),
  [Need Date] nvarchar(255),
  [Totals] nvarchar,
  [221] nvarchar(255),
  Month0 int,
  Month1 int,
  Month2 int,
  Month3 int,
  Month4 int,
  Month5 int,
  Month6 int,
  Month7 int,
  Month8 int,
  Month9 int,
  Month10 int,
  Month11 int,
  Month12 int,
  Month13 int,
  Month14 int,
  Month15 int,
  Month16 int,
  Month17 int,
  Month18 int,
  Month19 int,
  Month20 int,
  Month21 int,
  Month22 int,
  Month23 int,
  Month24 int,
  Month25 int,
  Month26 int
)


declare @current_month varchar(4000)
declare @all_months varchar(4000)

declare @this_date date, @next_date date, @first_date date, @column_name varchar(200)
declare @month_offset int
declare @output_sql nvarchar(max) = ''

declare crsr cursor for
    select try_convert(date,COLUMN_NAME) As the_date,
        COLUMN_NAME,
        lead(try_convert(date,COLUMN_NAME)) over (order by try_convert(date,COLUMN_NAME)) as next_date FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' and isdate(COLUMN_NAME) = 1 order by 1

open crsr

fetch next from crsr into  @this_date, @column_name, @next_date
set @first_date = @this_date
set @all_months = ''

while @@fetch_status <> -1
begin
    set @current_month = coalesce(@current_month,'') + case when @current_month > '' then '+' else '' end + 'cast([' + @column_name + '] as int)'
    set @month_offset = datediff(month,@this_date,@next_date)
    if @month_offset <> 0 or @next_date is null
    begin
        /* print cast(datediff(month,@first_date,@this_date) as varchar(20)) + ': ' + @current_month */

        set @output_sql = @output_sql + case when @output_sql > '' then ',' else '' end + 'Month' + cast(datediff(month,@first_date,@this_date) as varchar(20)) + ' = (' + @current_month + ')'
    set @all_months = @all_months + 'Month' + cast(datediff(month,@first_date,@this_date) as varchar(20)) + ','
        set @current_month = ''
    end

    fetch next from crsr into   @this_date, @column_name, @next_date
end

set @output_sql = 'INSERT dbo.Destination ([WC],[Requestor] ,[MTR#] ,[Date Added] ,[Use Case],[Prog Account],[SB#] ,[CO#] ,[Job #],[Need Date] ,[Totals],[221], ' + substring(@all_months,1,len(@all_months)-1) + ') SELECT [WC],[Requestor] ,[MTR#] ,[Date Added] ,[Use Case],[Prog Account],[SB#] ,[CO#] ,[Job #],[Need Date] ,[Totals],[221], ' + @output_sql + ' FROM dbo.MyTable'

print @output_sql
--exec sp_executesql @output_sql

close crsr
deallocate crsr
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works really well. One last question, How do i handle the NULLs while doing the SUM of week values? I know there is some tweak i need to put near an insert statement or at the variable @output_sql. For example if any of the week is NULL in a particular month, its returning NULL.

Comment: If you want the NULL values to be treated as zero, then make the following change:

`'cast([' + @column_name + '] as int)'`

becomes:

`'cast(isnull([' + @column_name + '],0) as int)'`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have  already implemented this yesterday and tested.